# MVC 5, DropDownList que esta en cascada

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework, mvc

Tengo el siguiente problema: de pronto, mi solución sea la que buscas en la parte del `controller` sea la que se necesite para tu modelo. Tengo el siguiente problema, lo que pasa es que si le doy a departamento y después a ciudad, la primera vez me sale bien pero al ir a grabar, no me permite ya que me dice que no podría guardar un valor de cero (what ever), estoy juicioso tomando las lecciones pero no he podido solucionar esta parte.

```js
        @section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#DepartamentID").change(function () {
                $("#CityID").empty();
                $("#CityID").append('<option value="0">[Select a City]</option>');
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetCities")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { departmentId: $("#DepartamentID").val() },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (i, data) {
                            $("#CityID").append('<option value="'
                             + data.departmentId + '">'
                             + data.Name + '</option>');
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (ex) {
                        alert('Failed to retrieve Cities.' + ex);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Estoy pensando que es en el Name (`data.Name`) que no me la reconoce la página... pues así es como la llame (yo por defecto siempre dejo la inicial con mayúscula, y ID es mayúscula) pero no se que abre hecho mal....

Ariel, pilas con lo siguiente... de promto te hace falta en el controlador de UserController.. //DropDownList -> cascate //Cundinamarca -> (los Municipios de este departamento, nada mas)

```
public JsonResult GetCities(int departmentId)
{
  db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
  var cities = db.Cities.Where(c => c.DepartamentID == departmentId);
  return Json(cities);
}
```

y después en la vista.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "The field {0} is required")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The field {0} must be maximum {1} Character length")]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    [Index("City_Name_Index", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

y me sigue saliendo el error:

> The value 'undefined' is not valid for City.

y si visualizo, yo tengo tanto departamentos (5) como ciudades (15).... y existe relación entre ellos, yo los tengo en Base de datos y estoy trabajando con Visual Studio 2015, sql server 2014, entity framework, se que esta parte es irrelevante pero para constatar que tengo todo lo correcto.

Comment: quien es Ariel ? cuando dice "Ariel, pilas con lo siguiente."

Comment: En el artículo que te indico a continuación, podrás ver cómo realizar un DropDownList  en cascada (Cascading DropDownList) en ASP.NET MVC. [Cómo crear un Cascading DropDownList en ASP.NET MVC](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2019/11/24/c%C3%B3mo-crear-un-cascading-dropdownlist-en-aspnet-mvc)